Computing the Degree, Closeness, Eigenvector, Katz, PageRank, and Betweenness centralities and accepting input from a file
i was trying to read from a text file in phyton but it's not doing it properly.
def read_city_data(file_path):
    cities = {}
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        next(file)  # Skip header line
        for line in file:
            try:
                city, latitude, longitude = line.strip().split('\t')
                if ' ' in city:
                    city = '"{}"'.format(city)
                cities[city] = (float(latitude), float(longitude))
            except ValueError:
                print("skipped")
                # Skip over lines with invalid format
                continue
    return cities

This was what how i was trying to read the text file, and this is the format of the text file:
City    Latitude    Longitude
Oradea    47.0465005    21.9189438
Zerind    46.622511    21.517419
Arad    46.166667    21.316667
Timisoara    45.759722    21.23
Lugoj    45.68861    21.90306
Mehadia    44.904114    22.364516
Drobeta    44.636923    22.659734
Craiova    44.333333    23.816667000000052
Sibiu    45.792784    24.152068999999983
Rimnicu Vilcea    45.099675    24.369318
Fagaras    45.8416403    24.9730954
Pitesti    44.860556    24.867778000000044
Giurgiu    43.9037076    25.9699265
Bucharest    44.439663    26.096306
Urziceni    44.7165317    26.641121
Eforie    44.058422    28.633607
Hirsova    44.6833333    27.9333333
Vaslui    46.640692    27.727647
Iasi    47.156944    27.590278000000012
Neamt    47.2    26.3666667

But it's not working, it just keeps printing skipped indicating it's an exception.
I was also trying to write functions that compute the centralities; degree, closeness, Eigenvector, betweenness, Katz, and pagerank for a graph of cities, but I can't find their implementations anywhere, i can only access them from the imported networkx library. If anyone happens to know to do this please share.

It could be because the words in the lines may not be tab separated. I replaced it with 4 spaces and your code worked just fine for me otherwise it showed 'skipped' like you reported. Please ensure that they are tab separated indeed. To confirm, try:
city, latitude, longitude = line.strip().split('    ') #4 spaces
